# Restore emacs' default undo/redo behavior in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, undo, undo-tree-mode

I've recently moved to spacemacs and it seems that they've adopted a different undo package (undo-tree) which I don't like since it does not push the undo actions back onto the history stack.  I would like to restore the default behavior but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

`C-/` is bound to `undo-tree-undo` in spacemacs.  I've tried to unbind this and use emacs' `undo` instead, but that does't seem to work.  I've added the following in my `user-config.el`:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-/"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'undo)
```

But the key remains bound to the undo-tree method.  I've also tried bind it to a new key, but the same seems to happen.  It's as if spacemacs redirects call to for `undo` to `undo-tree-undo`.  Is there anyway to fix this?  Thank you.

*EDIT*

I've also tried adding `undo-tree` to the `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages` but it doesn't seem to get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall undo-tree?

Comment: Can't uninstall it.  I tried using package-list-packages and uninstalling it but it will not let me mark it for deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, turns out the solution is easier then I imagined.  Just add the following to your `user-config.el` file:

```
(global-undo-tree-mode 0)
```